predict function used independently in RStudio shows the result considering all decimal places, but when it is inside a loop result is truncated? Why?
When predict function is used independently in RStudio, it shows the result by considering all decimal places, but when it is embedded in a loop, the result is truncated? Why?
I used different combinations of round but not got the same result as it was when predict function was used independently.

Can you illustrate this behaviour with a simple toy example?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
